# Compress a file and attach to email with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I have a script for take backup from my database:

```
<?php
 backup_tables('localhost','uname','pass','dbname');

/* backup the db OR just a table */
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{

    $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($name,$link);

    //get all of the tables
    if($tables == '*')
    {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
    }

    //cycle through
    foreach($tables as $table)
    {
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
        $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                for($j=0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) 
                {
                    $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                    $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                    if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                    if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                }
                $return.= ");\n";
            }
        }
        $return.="\n\n\n";
    }

    //save file
    $handle = fopen('db-backup-'.date("d_h-i").'.sql','w+');
    fwrite($handle,$return);
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

And, it creates a new backup every hour with cron (like "db-backup-31_03-01.sql")
It works and every thing is OK

But I need to attach the backup file to be compressed and send it to my email.
So, I just need a separate script to crate a zip from the last sql file and attach to email.

I found some scripts ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail)) for sending email, but I don't know how to zip the attachment before sending?

Or how can I create a compressed backup file with first script?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should automatically zip the backups on the server when you generate them; that way they will use less disk space on the server and your current problem goes away :-)

Comment: From PHP you can use Gzip.

Comment: @jeroen Yes, of course it would be a good option and it's my last question

Comment: Use gzencode
http://php.net/manual/es/function.gzencode.php
save result to a file, and attach it to email.

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosPHP, Could you give me a code for this?

Comment: Of course, no. Try yourself first. Now you know to compress. With file_put_contents you can write it down. And for the mail and attach file you can use phpmailer.

Comment: why do you not use mysqldump instead? it is easier to backup

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of code taken from https://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php...

```
/* creates a compressed zip file */
function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = false) {
    //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
    if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
    //vars
    $valid_files = array();
    //if files were passed in...
    if(is_array($files)) {
        //cycle through each file
        foreach($files as $file) {
            //make sure the file exists
            if(file_exists($file)) {
                $valid_files[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    //if we have good files...
    if(count($valid_files)) {
        //create the archive
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        //add the files
        foreach($valid_files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file,$file);
        }
        //debug
        //echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

        //close the zip -- done!
        $zip->close();

        //check to make sure the file exists
        return file_exists($destination);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your case, you could use it like this:

```
$files_to_zip = array(
    'db-backup-31_03-01.sql'
);
//if true, good; if false, zip creation failed
$result = create_zip($files_to_zip,'db_backup.zip');
```

Be sure to check that `$result` is TRUE before attempting to attach the zipped file to the email.